# How to put a figure with some subfigures in two columns in cas-dc class?

Tags: overleaf, elsarticle, els-cas

I use cas-dc class of Elsevier in Overleaf. I want to put a figure with some subfigures in two-column paper and my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,twocolumn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{appendix,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsthm,xspace,pdfsync,enumerate,graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{subcaption}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}% comment out if want end's to show
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\errorcontextlines\maxdimen

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=6cm]{10.png}
        \caption{ 10 }
         \label{10}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=6cm]{100.png}
        \caption{ 100 }
         \label{100}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=6cm]{500.png}
        \caption{500}
         \label{500}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=6cm]{1000.png}
        \caption{1000}
         \label{1000}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7cm,height=6cm]{5000.png}
        \caption{5000}
         \label{5000}
    \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Comparison }
        \label{Comparison }
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

But all figures have been shown in one column and two of them and also the caption have been shown out of the page (under the footnote) such that I cannot see them.
When I use elsarticle class instead of cas-dc:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{elsarticle}
```

it works correctly and all sub figures are in two column.
How can I fix the problem with cas-dc class?

Comment: In a two column document the `figure*` environment puts the figure across both columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document class `cas-dc` include some packages (for example `graphicx`) and also redefine them. It also require that some package had to be loaded in preamble, for example packages related to bibliography.

After rearranging your `figure` code, I obtain the following result:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[demo,
               a4paper,fleqn]
               {cas-dc} % this give one column document
                        % regardless that it is declared 
                        % as two columns document
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{natbib} % cas-cd require that this or similar bib package is loaded
\usepackage{lipsum} % 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=6cm} %set image parameters
\begin{subfigure}{6cm}
    \includegraphics{10.png}
    \caption{ 10 }
    \label{10}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{6cm}
    \includegraphics{100.png}
    \caption{ 100 }
    \label{100}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{6cm}
    \includegraphics{500.png}
\caption{500}
\label{500}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{6cm}
    \includegraphics{1000.png}
\caption{1000}
\label{1000}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{6cm}
    \includegraphics{5000.png}
\caption{5000}
\label{5000}
\end{subfigure}
%
\caption{Comparison }
\label{Comparison }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
In the case that you like to have two column document, than you need to add option ˙twocolumn` int document class options:

```
\documentclass[demo,
               a4paper,fleqn,
               twocolumn]{cas-dc}% now the document has two columns
```

and than for figures over two column use instead `figure` float `figure*`, as you use in the your document example.  With this changes the result is

[image]

**Edit (2)**
For unknown reason `cas-dc` doesn't produce two columns document without option `twocolumn` (tested with my local installation of MikTeX and with Overleaf service). Anyway, the second example has two columns and images are spread over two columns of text regardless how it is obtained.

**Addendum:**
In your document preamble are some packages duplicated and in a wrong order. So I try to clean-up and reorganize so that it has a more consistent pattern. At this I wonder, are you really need all these packages?

See, if the following preamble works for you:

```
\documentclass[demo,
               a4paper,fleqn,
               twocolumn]{cas-dc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} at new LaTeX version it is default 
\usepackage{natbib}
%math
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools} % nccmath had to be first, than mathtools
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,xspace}
\usepackage{autobreak}  % not recommended
% tables, units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% lists
\usepackage{enumerate}
% miscellaneous 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{cuted, float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
% algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}% comment out if want end's to show
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}

\usepackage{url}
\errorcontextlines\maxdimen

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text, not needed in real document
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but I had used these packages but I didn't write it in my question. My problem has not been solved and it still shows all figures in one column!

Comment: @hamta, sorry, but your document is one column only. What you expected? What is actually your problem?

Comment: My document is two-column because cas-dc is a class for double-column article (single-column (cas-sc.cls) and double-column (cas-dc.cls)) produced by Elsevier. And so I need to show the subfigures in two-column.

Comment: Thanks, I added twocolumn as you said but it shows all figures on right column again.

Comment: @hamta, please edit your question and provide your code which produce this result. With my MWE this is not a case. Apparently you not consider it as it is and make some unknown changes in it.

Comment: I edited my question an I add all packages that I use. When I run your code separately, it works well, but it doesn't work in my document. Do you think it is because of other packages?

Comment: @hamta, I test your document example. It works fine  (as desired). However it is worth to put some effort to organize your document preamble. Some packages are not in correct order, some are duplicated etc.

Comment: it has been solved. I think the problem was the size of figures. I deleted 
`[width=7cm,height=6cm]`
and I wrote :
`\begin{subfigure}{8cm}`
instead, for all figures and it works correctly.
Many thanks for your helps.

Comment: @hamta, instead of saying "thank you" you should accept my answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)